# Android java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask rejected from java.util.concurrent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, threadpool

I am creating an AsyncTask on thread pool on a Listview. I am handling those tasks through an array of AsyncTask.I have to remove those tasks when the fragment get destroyed and I have to again assign those tasks whenever I make a new fragment after destroying last one.

My code in the Listview adapter is:

```java
if(FragmentNowPlaying.task.isEmpty()){
        FragmentNowPlaying.task.add( new ProgressAsynchTask(holder.info,tvShows, position));
        FragmentNowPlaying.task.get(position).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
    else if(position >= FragmentNowPlaying.task.size()){
        FragmentNowPlaying.task.add( new ProgressAsynchTask(holder.info,tvShows, position));
        FragmentNowPlaying.task.get(position).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);    
    }
    else if(position < FragmentNowPlaying.task.size()){
    
        if(FragmentNowPlaying.task.get(position).getStatus().RUNNING == null){
            FragmentNowPlaying.task.remove(position);
            FragmentNowPlaying.task.add( new ProgressAsynchTask(holder.info,tvShows, position));
            FragmentNowPlaying.task.get(position).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else if(FragmentNowPlaying.task.get(position).getStatus().RUNNING != null){

            FragmentNowPlaying.task.get(position).cancel(true);
            FragmentNowPlaying.task.remove(position);
            FragmentNowPlaying.task.add( new ProgressAsynchTask(holder.info,tvShows, position));
            FragmentNowPlaying.task.get(FragmentNowPlaying.task.size()-1).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I couldn't remove and cancel last AsyncTask threads ,this is causing **rejectedExecuationException** and it´s not allowing me to create new threads as thread pool size get reached.
Please tell me how can I get over this issue?

Answer (score 4):

In your case it's easy to get this exception.
[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

> New tasks submitted in method execute(Runnable) will be rejected when the Executor has been shut down, and also when the Executor uses finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue capacity, and is saturated.

Task rejection lead to generation of [RejectedExecutionException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionException.html). In your case maximum number of threads are achieved. Threads and task limitation depends on Android platform version for example for Android 4.0.1 MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128.

That is why even if you have logic like in your example it's easy to reach thread limitation with 128 items in your list, especially if it's long runnig tasks.

I don't think that updating progress bar in a list require separate thread per list item. From my point of view it's enough one Thread or AsyncTask to complete this job. There is not enough of code to do appropriate refactoring but simplest concept to do that as follow:

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

//Somewhere in your activity

Thread updateThread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!isInterrupted()){
            final Map<Integer, Integer> progressStates = getCurrentProgress();
            uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        int progress = progressStates.get(i);
                        adapter.getItem(i).setProgress();//It's not default method you need to implement it in your item
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            try {
                sleep(1000); //Schedule next update in 1 second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Map getCurrentProgress(){
        //do long running operation here
        ...
        return progresStates;
    }
}.start();

//Don't forget stop this thread if user gone from screen. For example in your activity
public void onDestroy(){
    updateThread.interrupt();
}
```

If you actually has special thread (for example player thread) where progress is calculated, there is no need to start new one, just do progress update from this thread.

Comment: i want contiguous updates until it gets upto maxvalue ok i will manage this some how. and one thing more i want to ask how can i get this progressbar ?? actually i am trying but do not have any help .

Comment: ok i just replaced the line adapter.getItem(i).setProgress(); with

**((ProgressBar)(((ViewGroup) mImageGrid.getItemAtPosition(i)).getChildAt(3))).setProgress(progress);**

Comment: plz check it again . i have posted an answer .